# Multibyte-safe count distinct characters in a string

Tags: php, string, utf-8

I wan't to find a smart and efficient way of counting how many different alpha characters are in one string. Example:

```
$str = "APPLE";
echo char_count($str) // should return 4, because APPLE has 4 different chars 'A', 'P', 'L' and 'E'

$str = "BOB AND BOB"; // should return 5 ('B', 'O', 'A', 'N', 'D'). 

$str = 'PLÁTANO'; // should return 7 ('P', 'L', 'Á', 'T', 'A', 'N', 'O')
```

It should support UTF-8 strings!

Comment: Consider turning it into an array of characters (perhaps throwing out spaces) and then "unique'ing" the array. Unless there are some performance requirements (and a performance analysis showing they are not being met), then it is pretty smart and efficient-enough.

Comment: What charset encoding will the input have? UTF-8?

Comment: Yes UTF-8 chars. Forgot to add. I have modified my original post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're dealing with UTF-8 (which you really should consider, imho) none of the posted solutions (using strlen, str_split or count_chars) will work, as all of them treat one byte as one character (which is not true for UTF-8, obviously).

```
<?php

$treat_spaces_as_chars = true;
// contains hälöwrd and a space, being 8 distinct characters (7 without the space)
$string = "hällö wörld"; 
// remove spaces if we don't want to count them
if (!$treat_spaces_as_chars) {
  $string = preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', $string);
}
// split into characters (not bytes, like explode() or str_split() would)
$characters = preg_split('//u', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
// throw out the duplicates
$unique_characters = array_unique($characters);
// count what's left
$numer_of_characters = count($unique_characters);
```

If you want to throw out all non-word characters:

```
<?php

$ignore_non_word_characters = true;
// contains hälöwrd and PIE, as this is treated as a word character (Greek)
$string = "h,ä*+l•π‘°’lö wörld"; 
// remove spaces if we don't want to count them
if ($ignore_non_word_characters) {
  $string = preg_replace('/\W+/u', '', $string);
}
// split into characters (not bytes, like explode() or str_split() would)
$characters = preg_split('//u', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
// throw out the duplicates
$unique_characters = array_unique($characters);
// count what's left
$numer_of_characters = count($unique_characters);

var_dump($characters, $unique_characters, $numer_of_characters);
```

Comment: Correct, and I am dealing with UTF-8! I edited my original question.

Comment: I just added another example that ignores all non-characters (punctuation and stuff), you're likely not counting those either.

Answer (score 6):

Just use [count_chars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php):

```
echo count(array_filter(count_chars($str)));
```

The array returned from `count_chars()` will also tell you how many of each character are in the string.

Comment: +1 However, it is worth noting that spaces (and punctuation?) should be removed first as per the OP's example

Comment: @PrimozRome That is true, it returns an ascii map (256 characters) with a count of each character. Try the one I've suggested

Comment: @PrimozRome: Apologies I didn't filter the array for zero values, updated in the answer above.

Comment: @JuanMendes: I've fixed the answer above, single line is probably preferable. Kudos for your function though +1

Comment: @JuanMendes correct. I see yes. Your function works correctly, but not on UTF-8 strings. But still getting close to the result. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

count_chars returns a map of all the ascii characters, telling you how many of each there are in the string.  Here's a starting point for your own implementation.

```
function countchars($str, $ignoreSpaces) {
  $map = array();
  $len = strlen($str);
  for ($i=0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    if (!isset($map[$str{$i}])) {
      $map[$str{$i}] = 1;
    } else {
      $map[$str{$i}]++;
    }    
  }

  if ($ignoreSpaces) {
    unset($map[' ']);
  }

  return $map;
}

print_r(countchars('Hello World'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will do it, using the magic of associative arrays.  Works in linear time. (big O = `log(n)`)

```
function uniques($string){
   $arr = array();
   $parts = str_split($string);
   foreach($parts as $part)
      $arr["$part"] = "yup";
   return count($arr);
}

$str = "APPLE";
echo uniques($str);  // outputs 4
```

Answer (score 0):

My take on it,

```
$chars = array_count_values(str_split($input));
```

This will give you an associative array of unique letters as the key, and the number of occurrences as the value.

If you are not interested in the number of occurrences,

```
$chars = array_unique(str_split($input));
$numChars = count($chars);
```