# array_unique does not work on arabic alphabet strings

Tags: php

am trying to remove duplicates values from Arabic string input but

```
`$input = "اللہ";
$step1 = preg_split("/(?<!^)(?!$)/u", $input);
$step2 = implode(' ',step1);

$step3 = array_unique(step2 );

echo "step3";`
```

i need output like this

`ا ل ھ`

Comment: Absolutely wrong conclusion: _"array unique function not working on Arabic alphabets"_ - Correct view at the specific problem here: array_unique does not work on _strings_ - which is what implode gives you as a result.

Comment: Related: [Multibyte-safe count distinct characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7730059/2943403) and [Convert a String into an Array of Characters - multi-byte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55782088/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running a regular expression, you could use the **multibyte function `mb_str_split()` from the `mb_string` library**. It is made to handle special charsets. Your PHP config might already enable it to replace usual PHP functions, but in this case you should check your INI file, or you can add some `ini_set()` calls at the beginning of your code. But the easiest is just to call the `mb_*` functions.

Secondly, as @CBroe pointed out, you made a few mistakes in your code by passing a string to a function that wants an array as parameter.

This is what you can do:

```php
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');

$input = "اللہ";
$step1 = mb_str_split($input, 1, 'UTF-8');
print 'mb_str_split() returns ' . var_export($step1, true) . PHP_EOL;

$step2 = array_unique($step1);
print 'array_unique() returns ' . var_export($step2, true) . PHP_EOL;

print 'Desired output string is "' . implode(' ', $step2) . '"' . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
mb_str_split() returns array (
  0 => 'ا',
  1 => 'ل',
  2 => 'ل',
  3 => 'ہ',
)
array_unique() returns array (
  0 => 'ا',
  1 => 'ل',
  3 => 'ہ',
)
Desired output string is "ا ل ہ"
```

You can run it here: https://onlinephp.io/c/fe990

Comment: not working sir

Comment: Ok, could you explain and give us some details? I don't know arabic letters so it's also complicated for us to see what would be correct or incorrect. Can you give us a playground URL to try and solve your problem? What did you try yourself?

Comment: here is link check it sir [https://paiza.io/projects/ltQdnz1gWJF9yBIiVV5_dg]    you make your solution    play with echo    may be you understand not print   make it in echo     when am start in php file and run it no thing show on page @Patrick Janser   check the link           https://paiza.io/projects/ltQdnz1gWJF9yBIiVV5_dg

Comment: @Qaiser420 1) First link is broken. 2) Second link doesn't work because you left or added **code here!** in my PHP code... Remove it and run it!

Comment: ok sir am find the error why your code not working its php version problem your code working only on php 7.4 to up version   i have php 5 .4 version please check it  please give me solution in lower php version @Patrick Janser

Comment: Sir @Qaiser420, **[PHP 5.4](https://www.php.net/releases/#5.4.45) is more than 7 years old!** You shouldn't run such an old version as you'll have security problems. Update your PHP installation if you can. If not, **have you enabled the mbstring extension**?

Comment: thanks sir am update version working perfect [thanks]

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
$input = "اللہ";
$step1 = preg_split("/(?<!^)(?!$)/u", $input);
$step2 = implode(' ',$step1);
$step3 = str_split($step2);
$step4 = array_unique($step3);
$result = implode('', $step4);
echo "$result";
```

Comment: sir not working its only working for 5 to 6 string input not working on large values @Tech Geek

Comment: here is test see the error   [https://paiza.io/projects/Lw4RuCdx0LPCIXGpHRymzg?language=php]               please guide me why not working with more then 10 strings   @Tech Geek